# Synology join LDAP domain: failed to load user data

Tags: ldap, synology, apache-ds

I'm currently trying to setup SSO on a synology nas using Keycloak and ApacheDS. I've successfully joined the domain and can finally see all users and groups in the directory and I can edit the groups just fine. But I can't edit any of the users because of some nondescript error message `Failed to load the user data.`

I've joined my ldap with the following custom profile:

```
filter:
passwd = (objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
group = (objectClass=groupOfNames)

group:
cn = cn
gidNumber = HASH(cn)
memberUid = member

passwd:
uidNumber = HASH(uid)
uid = uid
userPassword = userPassword
gidNumber = HASH(memberOf)
```

Here is the test user i'm trying to edit (the password is SSHA hashed, because it won't let me set a cleartext password?)

```
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: top
cn: Test
sn: User
mail: test@domain.com
uid: test
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9c0xaU3NETmwxK3FpLzlDVFRFL1FaVDJUb2NRUTJFYnZnR3VQRVE9P
 Q==
```

The logs don't show anything, any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Synology requires the `memberOf`-Overlay attribute, which ApacheDS does not support. Switching to OpenLDAP and configuring the overlay fixed my problems.

Also, the `gidNumber` is for the user group, not for the group the user is part of and should be `HASH(cn)` or `HASH(uid)`.